# Problem reproducing MATLAB code in Python involving a for loop

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, for-loop, sympy

I have constructed the following code using MATLAB:

```
numero=60;
a=zeros(numero,1)
b=zeros(numero+1,1)   
for i=1:numero+1
    a(i)=-cos(pi*(i-1)/numero)
end
figure
plot(a,b, '*')
```

It serves to calculate the nodes of a Chebyshev polynomial of order `numero` and store it in a vector called `a`. 
I need to reproduce this in Python. My attempt at a solution is

```
from mpmath import chebyt, chop, taylor
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp


numero=60
nodes = []
for i in range(numero+2):
     auxiliary=-np.cos(np.pi*(i-1)/numero)
     nodes.append(auxiliary)

[float(i) for i in nodes]
nodes.sort()
print(nodes)
```

However, there are is an issue in python's output. The first is the fact that the second number of the list, `-0.9986295347545738` appears twice, it is also the third element of nodes. I don't know why this happens and I would like to know if someone can tell me how to avoid this error.

Comment: please, post your expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue comes about in this line:

```
for i in range(numero+2)
```

compared to:

```
for i=1:numero+1
```

The variable `i` is starting at `0`, and really we want it to start at `1`. We can see that this causes the error from the following:

```
>>> -np.cos(np.pi*(0-1)/numero)
-0.9986295347545738
>>> -np.cos(np.pi*(1-1)/numero)
1.0
>>> -np.cos(np.pi*(2-1)/numero)
-0.9986295347545738
```

etc. So the fix is to switch to:

```
for i in range(1, numero+2)
```

You can also omit these lines:

```
[float(i) for i in nodes]
nodes.sort()
```

This gives output:

```
[-1.0, -0.9986295347545738, -0.9945218953682733, -0.9876883405951378, ..., 0.9876883405951377, 0.9945218953682734, 0.9986295347545738, 1.0]
```

as expected.